# Ubuntu 13 Upgrade Issues

Tags: apt

I am new to Ubuntu so I'm not sure why I keep getting this every time I try to install/upgrade something. Below is just an example of the error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what ubuntu version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

That ppa is only available for Ubuntu up to 12.10 - http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/. As it is not supported, you might as well just remove it.

Open 'Software & Sources'
[image: Search for it and open it in Dash]

Then under the the <kbd>Other Software</kbd> tab, untick/remove the following:
[image: 'ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu saucy main' and 'ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu saucy main (Source Code)']

Exit, and press the <kbd>Reload</kbd>, or exit and run `sudo apt-get update`.

You may also be able to remove it by running:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:deluge-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```